# How to deny foreign alphabets in utf-8 in PHP 5.x (symfony)?

Tags: php, validation, utf-8, symfony1

I have to disable chinese, japanese, cyrillic (and so on) alphabets to be entered by users in my website, at validation time (only server side validation). At the same time I want all latin accented characters to be allowed.
I use symfony 1.1 and PHP 5.2, using utf-8, of course.
Any hint?

Comment: Sounds useless to me, as users from other countries will just use transliteration (e.g. Pinyin) to get around your limitations. Can you live with that? Or are you going to implement English dictionary matching too? ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can always convert to latin1 and then back again. That would discard any non latin1 characters. Eg.:

```
$str = utf8_encode(utf8_decode($str));
```

I wonder why you want this in the first place though?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pick and choose, you won't be able to avoid using regex and/or creating a list of allowed characters.

Yes this is not easy nor quick, but if you want to nit-pick characters, you might need to get specific.